# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date, UNION ALL, NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am totally confused as I get this error:
'Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date'

I have the following query where I get the error:

```
select top 1 a.[ID], a.[DateA], a.[DateD]  from  view1 a where a.ID]=1
union all 
(select top 1 a.[ID], a.[DateA], a.[DateD] from view2 a where a.[ID]=2 )
```

Data:

```
ID  DateA                       DateD
1   2021-01-09 00:00:00.000     NULL
2   2006-11-27 00:00:00.000     NULL
```

But if I change the query so there is directly null for column 'DateD', then its working fine, no error:

```
 select top 1 a.[ID], a.[DateA], null as [DateD]  from  view1 a where a.ID]=1
    union all 
 (select top 1 a.[ID], a.[DateA], a.[DateD] from view2 a where a.[ID]=2 )
```

In the first view (under the hood) I have
select NULL as [DateD]
and in the second view (under the hood) I have:
select CAST(DateD AS DATE) AS [DateD]

What is the issue?

Comment: Check your views, `[DateD]` will be an `int` in the first view. Use `CONVERT(DATE, NULL)` in the view to fix it

Comment: The datasets in the `UNION (ALL)` must all have the same definition. Clearly they do not, and hence the error. This would suggest one of your "date" columns is *not* a `date`, but an `int` (which I would suggest is a design flaw).

Comment: I guarantee that there's no column named `ID]` in `view1`, which means you're showing us code that you can only *guess* produces the error you're asking about because you're never run this code. I'd suggest you spend a little time creating some mock data and tables in a scratch database, get to the point where you have an *actual query that generates the error*, and then please post all of those details so we can recreate the issue locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SQL Server encounters `NULL` and has to figure out a type, the default is `int`.  You can easily see this if you do:

```
select null as x
into t;
```

and then look at the definition of `x` (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e07bbd3b3d46bf75870d78a93a75aeb5)).

So, to get a `NULL` of a different type, cast it:

```
select cast(null as date) as x
```

You need to do this in the view.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct and it worked out.